# Javascript new Map return reference of the object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I have a javascript Map

```
var map1 = new Map();
map1.set('bar',{"foo":"baz"});
var obj = map1.get('bar')
```

When I change the value of obj the map value also changed

```
obj.foo = "abc"
console.log(map1.get("bar")) //{"foo":"abc"}
```

Why is that? and how to stop this behavior?
I know we can use the `Object.assign()` to unlink the reference, but I need to do every time when I get from Map then. Is there any alternative solution of the best way to do it?

Comment: This behaviour sounds logic. Otherwise how to change something inside object in map?

Comment: We have set method for that. map1.set()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could monkey patch `get` and return always a copy.

```js
var map1 = new Map();

map1.get = function (ref) {
    return function (k) {
        return Object.assign({}, ref.call(this, k));
    };
}(map1.get);

map1.set('bar', { foo: "baz" });
var obj = map1.get('bar');

obj.foo = "abc"
console.log(map1.get("bar"));
```

Comment: He know Object.assign but he don't want to use that

Comment: @Faly, somwhere a copy is necessary. now it's in the `get` method.

Comment: It's completely bad idea to override such methods. Imagine you will enter a project, where any standard method can be overridden. Support of such project will be pretty high

Comment: i am aware of the problem, but i am overwriting only the method of `map1`, not the prototype of `Map`.

Comment: is this approach is violation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle?

Comment: @NinaScholz as I am implemented Map not more than three or four places so your patch helps me and also not needed to write Object.assign before every get method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Object.assign removes the reference only from the first level, so things will go crazy when you start using more complex objects like {"foo":{"baz":"bar"}}.